# Pop up menu event control in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, events, popup, action

When I add a pop up menu in Qt as follows:

```
QMenu menu(widget);
menu.addAction("AAA");
menu.exec(eventPress->globalPos());
```

How do I control *"AAA"* action events. e.g. do something when *"AAA"* is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overloaded addAction.

> From Qt assistant
>   This convenience function creates a new action with the text text and
>   an optional shortcut shortcut. The action's triggered() signal is
>   connected to the receiver's member slot. The function adds the newly
>   created action to the menu's list of actions and returns it.

```
MyClass::Popup()
{
QMenu menu(widget);
menu.addAction("AAA", this, SLOT(burnCase()));
menu.exec(eventPress->globalPos());
}

// This is your slot
MyClass::burnCase()
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you also say how to open an sub-action, when "AAA" is clicked?

Comment: QAction* a = menu.addAction("AAA",...); a->setMenu(Your Submenu), Please check following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781198/how-to-add-menu-dynamically-in-qt